# WAN light is not stedy in netis 2411 router

Tags: router, connection

I m facing a problem unable to have wifi connection, as the netis router light is not steady.how to fix this?

Comment: What have you tried/researched so far? I assume you have tried restarting your router. Which light isn't steady? Could it be an ISP problem?

Answer (score 0):

the following things could help:

1)Reboot the router - turning it off and on again genuinely works for a lot of problems.

2)factory reset the router - just incase it has been misconfigured - reconfiguring it from scratch will overwrite any wrong configurations

3)Try a different router.  If the problem persists, its your ISPs problem, if it goes away, its time to replace the router.

Hope this helps.